# Access Class variables inside navigator.permissions.query function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio-recording

I am trying to request permission from the user to record audio using AngularJs.

I have this method in my Component Class, but the class variables are not accessible using `this`.

```
public recordAnswer(event: any) {

    this.recording = true;
    this.toastr.error('Something went wrong. Try again.'); // this line works

    navigator.permissions.query({name: 'microphone'}).then(function (result) {

        console.log(result);

        if (result.state == 'granted') {
            // start recording audio
        } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {

        } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
            console.log(this.psp); // this line does not work
            this.toastr.error('Something went wrong. Try again.'); // this line does not work
        }

        result.onchange = function () {};
    });

}
```

I am getting this error:-

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'psp')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'psp')

I had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback), but I am not sure how I can access the class variables of `MyComponent`.

How can I access class variables so I can display a `toastr.error` to inform user to give permission?

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer for this one. `navigator.permissions.query({name: 'microphone'}).then(this.processPermissionResult.bind(this));`

Comment: I created a new function `public processPermissionResult(result : any) {}`. and transferred the contents to the new function and binded the `this` variable to the callback.(in the above comment)